How to show database json column values in filament php table
I have a json column in my database table which stores the foreign keys, the field name is cast as array on the model. I am using multiple select with a relationship and the record get saved as expected. However, I don't know how to show them on the table using the relationship.
When I use the table column name I get the stored IDs. When I use the relationship name I get all the related records in a json format, how do I get the name key from this
{"id":1,"name":"People"}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
